# Property in a new instance of class and previously created instance of same class are referenced same memory

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, valuetuple, bindableproperty

```
// Interface 
public interface IItem
{
    Collection Collection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Collection : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<People>), typeof(Collection), new ObservableCollection<People>(), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);
    public ObservableCollection<People> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<People>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }
}

//Model class.
public class People
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


//Core logic implementation.
public class SourceItems :BindableObject, IItem
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CollectionProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Collection", typeof(Collection), typeof(SourceItems), new Collection(), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);

    public Collection Collection
    {
        get { return (Collection)GetValue(CollectionProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
    }
}


Public class MainPage()
{
        var firstsource = new SourceItems();
        firstsource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name= "People1" });
        firstsource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name = "People2" });
        firstsource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name = "People3" });

        var secondSource = new SourceItems();
        secondSource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name = "People4" });
        secondSource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name = "People5" });
        secondSource.Collection.Items.Add(new People() { Name = "People6" });
}
```

Here i have created two different object for class 'SourceItems' after executing above code instance of firstsource.Collection.Items holds 6 items and secondSource.Collection.Items also holds same 6 items.
it should be 3.

please clarify me what i'm doing wrong.

[image]

i have showed both the instance value while debugging.

Comment: @Sach yes , you are right after executing line 6 both the instance value is 6 , but it should be 3 not 6. because both or different instance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `firstsource` and `secondSource` is different in your code, while `firstsource.Collection` is the same Collection as `secondSource.Collection`.

Because when you perform `set/get` method(`add new items`) to `firstsource.Collection` or `secondSource.Collection`, they all point to  `public static readonly BindableProperty CollectionProperty`, it's a static property so it's shared in all SourceItems instances as `Jeppe Stig Nielsen` mentioned in his answer.

That's why `firstsource.Collection.Items` holds 6 items and `secondSource.Collection.Items` also holds same 6 items. They are the same Collection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that you using `new ObservableCollection<People>()` as default value. This means that every instance will use the same instance. The `new ObservableCollection<People>()` is only executed ones.

You could assign the Collection property a new ObservableCollection

```
var firstsource = new SourceItems();
firstsource.Collection = new ObservableCollection<People>();
```

or

```
public class Collection : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<People>), typeof(Collection), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, null);
    public ObservableCollection<People> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<People>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    } = new ObservableCollection<People>();
}
```

Or use a constructor.

Comment: in this approach both the instance holds 3 items , problem is both are same.

while creating and assigning new instance to secondSource , firstSource items are cleared ,

while adding items in secondSource same value is added in firstSource items

Comment: I do not think you can have an initializer on a property which is not automatically generated. So while `public T N { get; set; } = initial;` is OK, what you write, `public T N { get { /*...*/ } set { /*...*/ } } = initial;` is ___not___ allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CollectionProperty` is a ***`static`*** field, so the same instance is shared between all `SourceItems` instances.

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) document they have mentioned to declare static property to create bindable property

public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create ("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);